# Parse Nested Url Encoded Data from POST Request

Tags: python, django, post, webhooks, mailchimp

I am currently creating a callback URL in Django for a webhook in Mailchimp where Mailchimp will send a POST request with urlencoded data in the form of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

The issue I have run into is that the data returned contains nested data. Some of the data in this urlencoded string looks like its defining nested JSON, which I believe is non-standard (I could be mistaken, though).

For example, one POST request from Mailchimp, which is sent when a user changes their name, would look like:

`type=profile&fired_at=2021-05-25+18%3A03%3A23&data%5Bid%5D=abcd1234&data%5Bemail%5D=test%40domain.com&data%5Bemail_type%5D=html&data%5Bip_opt%5D=0.0.0.0&data%5Bweb_id%5D=1234&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BEMAIL%5D=test%40domain.com&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BFNAME%5D=first_name&data%5Bmerges%5D%5BLNAME%5D=last_name&data%5Blist_id%5D=5678`

Using Django's `request.POST`, the data is decoded into:

```
{
    'type': 'profile',
    'fired_at': '2021-05-25 18:03:23',
    'data[id]': 'abcd1234',
    'data[email]': 'test@domain.com',
    'data[email_type]': 'html',
    'data[ip_opt]': '0.0.0.0',
    'data[web_id]': '1234',
    'data[merges][EMAIL]': 'test@domain.com',
    'data[merges][FNAME]': 'first_name',
    'data[merges][LNAME]': 'last_name',
    'data[list_id]': '5678'
}
```

This looks really ugly in practice, since to access the first name of the user from `request.POST` we would have to do

```
request.POST.get("data['merges']['FNAME']", None)
```

The data is obviously intended to look like

```
{
    'type': 'profile',
    'fired_at': '2021-05-25 18:03:23',
    'data': {
        'id': 'abcd1234',
        'email': 'test@domain.com',
        'email_type': 'html',
        'ip_opt': '0.0.0.0',
        'web_id': '1234',
        'merges':{
            'email': 'test@domain.com',
            'fname': 'first_name',
            'lname': 'last_name',
        },
        'list_id': '5678'
    },
}
```

and be accessed like

```
data = request.POST.get('data', None)
first_name = data['merges']['FNAME']
```

I have looked for a Django/Python specific way to decode this nested URL-encoded data into more appropriate formats to work with it in Python, but have been unable to find anything. Python's `urllib` library provides methods such as [urllib.parse.parse_qs()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) to decode urlencoded strings, but these methods do not handle this nested type data.

Is there a way to properly decode this nested urlencoded data using Django/Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard library nor Django utility function for this.

We can implement `convert_form_dict_to_json_dict` as such:

1. Initialise `json_dict` to an empty dict `{}`.
2. For each `form_key`, using the example `'data[merges][EMAIL]'`,

   1. Use regex to obtain `nested_keys`, i.e. `('data', 'merges', 'EMAIL')`.
   2. Determine `last_nesting_level`, i.e. `2` from nesting levels `(0, 1, 2)`.
   3. Initialise `current_dict` to `json_dict`.
   4. For each `nesting_level, current_key`, i.e. `0, 'data'`, `1, 'merges'`, `2, 'EMAIL'`,

      1. If it is before `last_nesting_level`, get next `current_dict` using `current_key`.
      2. Else, set `current_dict` entry for `current_key` to `value`.
3. Return `json_dict`.

```py
import re


def convert_form_dict_to_json_dict(form_dict):
    json_dict = {}
    for form_key, value in form_dict.items():
        nested_keys = (re.match(r'\w+', form_key).group(0), *re.findall(r'\[(\w+)]', form_key))
        last_nesting_level = len(nested_keys) - 1
        current_dict = json_dict
        for nesting_level, current_key in enumerate(nested_keys):
            if nesting_level < last_nesting_level:
                current_dict = current_dict.setdefault(current_key, {})
            else:
                current_dict[current_key] = value
    return json_dict
```

Usage:

```py
POST_dict = {
    'type': 'profile',
    'fired_at': '2021-05-25 18:03:23',
    'data[id]': 'abcd1234',
    'data[email]': 'test@domain.com',
    'data[email_type]': 'html',
    'data[ip_opt]': '0.0.0.0',
    'data[web_id]': '1234',
    'data[merges][EMAIL]': 'test@domain.com',
    'data[merges][FNAME]': 'first_name',
    'data[merges][LNAME]': 'last_name',
    'data[list_id]': '5678'
}

from pprint import pprint
pprint(convert_form_dict_to_json_dict(POST_dict))
```